# Calculate(SUM(..)..) vs SUMX

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I am trying to sum an amount column based on p_region, statuscode, date range and dollar amount.*

When I try with CALCULATE(SUM()), I cannot get all the clauses that I need.

```
<£50k =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( tsg_enquiries[tsg_quoteprice_base] ),
    tsg_enquiries[statuscode] = 866120000
        || tsg_enquiries[statuscode] = 866120007,
    tsg_enquiries[tsg_quoteprice_base] <= 49999
)
```

The above is missing the date range clause.

```
tsg_enquiries[createdon] >=  'LTM Live'[xxxBegin] &&`  
tsg_enquiries[createdon]  <= 'LTM Live'[xxxEnd]`
```

When I try SUMX(), I cannot evaluate the amount.

```
£ALL =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        tsg_enquiries,
        tsg_enquiries[pc_regionno] = 'LTM Live'[pc_regionno]
            && tsg_enquiries[statuscode] = 866120000
            || tsg_enquiries[statuscode] = 866120007
            && tsg_enquiries[statuscode] = 'LTM Live'[pc_regionno]
            && tsg_enquiries[createdon] >= 'LTM Live'[xxxBegin]
            && tsg_enquiries[createdon] <= 'LTM Live'[xxxEnd]
    ),
    tsg_enquiries[tsg_quoteprice_base]
)
```

The above is missing the amount clause.

`tsg_enquiries[tsg_quoteprice_base]<=49999`

[image: screenshot]

How can I get my desired result?

Comment: Why can't you put the amount clause in the `FILTER`?

Answer (score 1):

If you use complex conditions in filter function, every condition should act on only one column. You could use CalculateTable function, may be. The follows is an example:

```
SUMX( CALCULATETABLE('InternetSales_USD', 'DateTime'[CalendarYear]=2002)
 , [SalesAmount_USD])
```

Comment: In your example, can you filter by the amount that you wish to sum? For example, order_amount < 50000

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to add `tsg_enquiries[tsg_quoteprice_base]<=49999` to the criteria in your second query (that uses `SUMX`)?  You can use the `AND` function, with the initial set of filters as the first argument and `tsg_enquiries[tsg_quoteprice_base]<=49999` as the second.  While not necessary, you may also want to considered replacing the `&&` and `||` for readability.

```
£ALL =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        tsg_enquiries,
        AND (
            tsg_enquiries[pc_regionno] = 'LTM Live'[pc_regionno]
                && tsg_enquiries[statuscode] = 866120000
                || tsg_enquiries[statuscode] = 866120007
                && tsg_enquiries[statuscode] = 'LTM Live'[pc_regionno]
                && tsg_enquiries[createdon] >= 'LTM Live'[xxxBegin]
                && tsg_enquiries[createdon] <= 'LTM Live'[xxxEnd],
            tsg_enquiries[tsg_quoteprice_base] <= 49999
        )
    ),
    tsg_enquiries[tsg_quoteprice_base]
)
```